# Play animation when user stop hovering over image with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have the following css code that I use on some images that act like buttons on my website:

```css
figure {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

figure:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition-duration: .8s;
  box-shadow: 5px 15px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<figure></figure>
```

It works well, but when the user stop hovering the image goes back to its initial place (undo the transform translateY) and it does not look good. I would like to add an animation with a duration of 0.8s when the user stop hovering so that the image returns to its place smoothly. Any ideas?

Comment: @keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
Just an example for you to follow. The most important thing is the keyframe, make sure you have it

Comment: Put the transition on the base state...not the hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `transition-duration: .8s` on `figure`. If you apply transition on the element itself it works on both on-hover state and off-hover state.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
figure {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition-duration: .8s;
}

figure:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  box-shadow: 5px 15px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<figure></figure>
```

You also can change the duration time of both on-hover state and off-hover state like

**On-Hover**

```
figure:hover {
  transition-duration: .8s;  /* It will run when you hover on your element */
}
```

**Off-Hover**

```
figure {
  transition-duration: .4s;  /* It will run when you move cursor from your element */
}
```

> *Reference Link:* [***transition CSS***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)